# Why is ruler reversed on word 2016 when updating TOC?

Tags: microsoft-word

When trying to update toc the ruler gets reversed and the text header aligns to right while the page number aligns left with ... leaders. I am using English text, left to right and this happens only when updating toc.

Comment: Check the formatting the TOC style names. They might be marked with an RTL language setting.

Comment: @Rich Michaels They seem English, unless i am missing something? How do i check those Right-To-Left language setting? I briefly saw it was Asian (Japanese) on toc2 which i am using, i edited it, but the problem persists.

Comment: If the Style has a Language setting and the language specified, such as Japanese is an RTL language, then that is Word's indicator. You'll have to modify those styles and remove the language setting.